# Oracle SQL CURSOR Update with Join and Commit

Tags: oracle, plsql, sql-update, cursor

i want to update a table with the value of another table. But: I need a commit after every 50000 rows. I don't want to discuss why and I know the tip to create a new table instead of update, but this is not an option. I need only help with the query.

For update after x rows I found this:

```
DECLARE
  i NUMBER := 0;
  CURSOR G1 IS SELECT * FROM test_new 
               FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
  FOR c1 IN S1 LOOP
      UPDATE test SET col1 = 'somevalue1'
             WHERE CURRENT OF G1;

      i := i + 1;              -- Commits after every X number of records
      IF i > 1000 THEN
         COMMIT;
         i := 0;
      END IF;

  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

To Update a table with another table this code works:

```
DECLARE
  l_r_id test_new.id_customer%type;
  l_r_name test_new.name%type;
  i NUMBER := 0;
  CURSOR CUR is select tnw.id_customer, tnw.name
                from test_new tnw
                   , test tes
                where tnw.id_customer = tes.id_customer
    FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur;
    LOOP 
      FETCH cur
       INTO l_r_id, l_r_name;
      UPDATE test
         set name = l_r_name
       where test.id_customer = l_r_id;
      i := i+1;
      EXIT WHEN cur%notfound;
    END LOOP;
    commit;

END;
```

But I don't know how to get

```
  IF i > 50000 THEN
     COMMIT;
     i := 0;
  END IF;
```

into the code. It seems there is a problem with FETCH and Commit. I get the Error Message from Oracle:

2) If the cursor has been opened with the FOR UPDATE clause, fetching after a COMMIT has been issued will return the error.

Does anybody have an idea? I know there have been a way to join without "FETCH" but I don't know how. Like I said earlier, please only help with the code, no discussion about update and commit.

Comment: [Tom Kyte about frequent commits](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022): "**is wrong, wrong, wrong. So wrong.... So very very wrong.**"

Comment: Something like this maybe? https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-BC564905-51F4-4ADB-B300-9F15B1AC3099

Comment: What error? Also, in your first example your `g1` cursor is `select from test_new for update` but then you update a different table `where current of g1` which I would expect to give `ORA-01410: invalid ROWID`. In your second example I am not clear why you switched from a Cursor FOR loop to the more verbose and less efficient OPEN-FETCH-EXIT-CLOSE syntax.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't found out how to join with the first example and the second one worked perfectly. I know Tom Kyte have an opinion on this topic, he makes it very clear. I wouldn't use it in an ETL-Job, but for a good and well tested onetime Update it's very helpful.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson is correct.. `for update` and `current of` should be on same table..

Comment: Yes, the first statement ist wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

`Exit` must be after `fetch`, if the cursor has no data, the loop will beterminated.

At the end of the loop, you can then query your commit as follows.
So your loop can look like this

```
LOOP 
  FETCH cur
   INTO l_r_id, l_r_name;
  EXIT WHEN cur%notfound;

  UPDATE test
     set name = l_r_name
   where test.id_customer = l_r_id;
  i := i+1;
  if mod(i,50000) = 0 then
    commit;
  end if;

END LOOP;
```

Another suggestion would be to define a collection of records.
Fill the collection with the data from the table `test_new`. then to iterate over this collection and make an update.

without testing it, the solution could look like this.

```
DECLARE

  TYPE tabTest IS TABLE OF test_new%ROWTYPE;
  t_test tabTest;
  i NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
  select tnw.* 
    bulk collect into t_test
    from test_new tnw
       , test tes
    where tnw.id_customer = tes.id_customer

  for indx  in 1 .. t_test.count()
  loop
    UPDATE test
       set name = t_test(indx).name
     where test.id_customer = t_test(indx).id;

    i := i+1;
    if mod(i,50000) = 0 then
      commit;
    end if;

  end loop;
  commit;
END;
```

Comment: The first example get to the same error:  2) If the cursor has been opened with the FOR UPDATE clause, fetching after a COMMIT has been issued will return the error."

Comment: But with the second and some changes it works. t_test.count() doesn't work, but I set a variable with a count.

Answer (score 0):

My solution with the help of @hotfix:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE tabTest IS TABLE OF test_new%ROWTYPE;
       t_test tabTest;
  testcount number;
  i NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  select count(*) into testcount from test_new;

  select tnw.* 
    bulk collect into t_test
    from test_new tnw
       , test tes
    where tnw.id_customer = tes.id_customer;  

  FOR cur IN 1..testcount LOOP
      UPDATE test 
        set name = t_test(cur).name
        where test.id_customer = t_test(cur).id_customer;

      i := i + 1;              -- Commits after every X number of records

      IF i > 50000 THEN
         COMMIT;
         i := 0;
      END IF;

  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```